# printing binary tree to file

Tags: java, save, binary-tree

I have a method that is supposed to print a binary tree to a file. This is it:

```
public void writeFile(Node mainNode)
{
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    try
    {

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("BinaryTree.txt");
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream); 


        while(mainNode != null)
        {
             writeFile(mainNode.leftChild);
             printWriter.print(mainNode);
             writeFile(mainNode.rightChild); 

        }

        printWriter.close();

  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     System.out.println("An error occured");
      printWriter.close();
  }

}
```

The problem is that it seems to eternally loop as it's not finding the end of the tree. Is there anything I can try.

Here's the Node class too.

```
class Node
{
int id;
int grade;
String name;

Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;


Node(int id, int grade, String name )
{
    this.id = id;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.name = name;
}


public String toString()
{
    return name + " has a grade of " + grade + " and their ID is " + id;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect this loop to end:

```
while(mainNode != null) {
    // never change mainNode
}
```

You need to pass your `PrintWriter` as an argument to your function, in order for all recursive calls to write (append) to the same file. Then provide a base case to stop:

```
public void writeFile(Node mainNode, PrintWriter w)
{
    if (mainNode == null)  // base case to stop recursion  
        return;
    top_call = false;  // Flag needed later
    if (w == null) {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("BinaryTree.txt");
        w = new PrintWriter(outputStream); 
        top_call = true;  // mark highest entry point to know when to close writer
    }
    writeFile(mainNode.leftChild, w);
    w.print(mainNode);
    writeFile(mainNode.rightChild, w);

    if (top_call)  // don't close writer in recursive calls
        w.close();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. You might want to elaborate a bit more, though. I didn't see that at first! Good thinking.

Comment: Well, when the mainNode returns null then it should break out. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Allan Well, the mainNode is not null when you enter the loop and it then never changes. The recursive calls inside are just repeated over and over even though somewhere in these recursive calls, there might be a null mainNode

Comment: How do I know when the binary tree ends then?

Comment: @Allan, since you're using recursion, by principle it will finish, i.e. start going back, as soon as mainNode is null. This behavior is applicable on both sides of the tree.

Comment: Yes, but how do I code in that behavior. It doesn't seem to print to the file either. Sorry, I'm new the Binary trees and recursion.

Comment: Just follow @schwobaseggl answer.

Comment: I just seen it there, Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 1):

The entire `writeFile` method is wrong.

You have a loop over a single value without any go-to-next, so it'll never end.

It also calls itself recursively, trying to open the file *again* inside the recursive call. That's going to fail.

You have to split the method in two:

- First method open the file, calls second method, then closes file (using try-with-resources, please!).
- Second method does the three lines of call-self(left), write node, call-self(right).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for anyone who'd like to know.

```
public void writeFile(Node mainNode)
{
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;

    try
    {

        outputStream = new FileOutputStream("BinaryTree.txt");
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream); 

        write(mainNode, printWriter);

        printWriter.flush();

  }catch(IOException e)
  {
     System.out.println("An error occured");
      printWriter.close();
  }

}

 public void write(Node mainNode, PrintWriter w)
 {
     if(mainNode != null){
      write(mainNode.leftChild, w);
      w.print(mainNode);
      write(mainNode.rightChild, w); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an array to store nodes's data (Left - Node - Right)
before this i write the data of the array to the file i want.

```
void LNR(TREE t, int a[], int &i){
   if(t != NULL)
   {
       LNR(t ->pLeft, a, i);
       a[i] = t ->data;
       i++;
       LNR(t ->pRight, a, i);
   }
}

void Output(const char *outfile, TREE t){
    int a[100];
    int i = 0;
    LNR(t, a, i);
    ofstream out;
    out.open(outfile);
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
       cout << "Unble to open the file.";
    }
    else
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
       {
           if (j < i)
               out << a[j] << " ";
           else
               out << a[j];
       }
    }
}
```